# how to make a dynamic url redirect using django after google authentication

Tags: python, django, google-authentication, slug

By using Django framework I built multiple store based website, each having different slug.

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/<slug:slug>
```

I want to open a google authentication when we visit the above URL. After the verification is complete I want to redirect them to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/<slug:slug>/shopitems
```

I had successfully implemented google authentication with static URL but not dynamic (using slug variable) like the above.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the `@login_required` decorator on the view function handling the route.
If you are using class-based views, you can use `LoginRequiredMixins` to prevent unauthenticated users to access that route and redirect them to the login page. When they successfully log in, Django will automatically redirect them to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/<slug:slug>/shopitems`.

Comment: but the problem is, the redirecting url is given in the settings.py as:'SITE_ID = 2
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /customerapp/fixedredirect' and we cant pass any variable in settings.py